# css doesn't apply on Icon using dom

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, addeventlistener

Hello I am trying to change the color of icon using dom. When I do that changing icon to h6 and instead of icon-exclamation use the text ! it works. How to apply it on the icon.
Html code which do it:

```
<div class ="indicator">
                    <i id ="exclamation" class = "icon-exclamation"></i>
                    <h6 id = "pinfo" class ="passwordinfo" >dupa</h6>
            </div>

<script>
            var pass = document.getElementById("password");
            var pinfo =document.getElementById("pinfo");
            var exc = document.getElementById("exclamation");
            console.log(exc[0])
            pass.addEventListener('input', ()=>
            {
    
                if (pass.value.length === 0)
                {
                    pinfo.innerHTML = "Waiting for your password"
                }
                else if (pass.value.length <=4)
                {
                    pinfo.style.visibility = "visible";
                    exc.style.color = "blue";
                    exc.style.display = "block";
                    // exc.style.display = 'block';
                    pinfo.innerHTML = "Password is weak";
                    pinfo.style.color = "#ff0000"
    
    
                }
                else if (pass.value.length >=4 && pass.value.length <8)
                {
                    pinfo.innerHTML = "Password is medium";
                    pinfo.style.color ="#ff8000";
                }
                else
                {
                    pinfo.innerHTML = "Password is strong";
                    pinfo.style.color = "#00ff00";
                }
    
            })
        </script>
```

Why this code doesn't work and how to change the color of the icon dynamically?

Comment: Can you add the full html including the inputs?

Comment: Probably I can but I am using fontenello and you won't see the icon without that

Comment: You should include proper library to use icons, like `fontawesome`

Comment: The problem is that  I can see the icon but I cannot change the color of it

Comment: Yes, like @DreamBold said we can't see where is element with id="password" coming from. You're missing something like <input id="password" ....... in your html

Comment: I have updated the answer, it should solve your problem. @New_stud

Answer (score 1):

Your code works correctly, you might have not included all the assets including fonts and CSS files. You can have a look at the working code here: `https://codesandbox.io/s/mutable-sea-fl3320?file=/src/index.js`

[image]

You can read more about how to use fontello icons in your code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17288478/how-do-i-use-fontello-fonts).

You can use `fontawesome` instead of `fontello`, of course. It's more simple and more robust for most situations.
In your HTML file, please add the first line to add the `fontawesome` CSS library, and instead of the commented line, try to use `fontawesome` icon.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="indicator">
  <input id="password" />
  <input id="pinfo" />

<!--   <i  class="icon-exclamation"></i> -->
  <i id="exclamation" class="fa fa-exclamation-circle fa-2x"></i>
  <h6 id="pinfo" class="passwordinfo">dupa</h6>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: But the problem is tham I am using fontello not fontawesome

Comment: Can you add the link to `fontello` here?

Comment: You need to download files and there are a lot of them. But if it works with fontawesome

Comment: Looks to me you're using font awesome v3: https://fontawesome.com/v3/icon/exclamation

Comment: Your icon seems to be the same as this one `fa fa-exclamation-circle`, just replace it with `fa-exclamation` and you'll see the same icon as you have now. @New_stud

Comment: I have implemented the fully working code here as you did: `https://codesandbox.io/s/mutable-sea-fl3320?file=/src/index.js` @New_stud

Answer (score 0):

If i well understood, if you want to change dinamically the icon color as you change the pinfo, you just have to put **exc.style.color** inside the ifs you want to change..

May be something like this:

```
pass.addEventListener('input', () => {
            if (pass.value.length === 0)
            {
                pinfo.innerHTML = "Waiting for your password"
            }
            else if (pass.value.length <=4)
            {
                pinfo.style.visibility = "visible";
                exc.style.color = "blue";
                exc.style.display = "block";

                pinfo.innerHTML = "Password is weak";
                pinfo.style.color = "#ff0000"
            }
            else if (pass.value.length >=4 && pass.value.length <8)
            {
                pinfo.innerHTML = "Password is medium";
                pinfo.style.color ="#ff8000";
                exc.style.color = "orange";
            }
            else
            {
                pinfo.innerHTML = "Password is strong";
                pinfo.style.color = "#00ff00";
                exc.style.color = "yellow";
            }

        })
```